# Are purchasing items through apps against the rules of the App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

From the App Store's Review Guidelines:

> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected

So, what that statement really mean? Does it mean that purchasing apps, like clients for online stores are not accepted? If this is true, why applications like Amazon and eBay are available in the App Store?

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is answered on StackOverflow; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050296/apple-in-app-purchase-and-physical-digital-goods/36147796

Comment: @GrahamMiln The question is not answered completely there.

Comment: The question has [already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050296/apple-in-app-purchase-and-physical-digital-goods/36147796) and has attracted answers. I feel it is better not to split a good set of answers across two near identical questions. Ultimately, any answer will be reduced to "ask Apple"; only Apple's app review staff can make a ruling on what is allowed in their store.

Comment: @GrahamMiln So when I cannot find my answer in someone's question, and I don't want to waste my reputation for bounty, what can I do instead of asking a new question?

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled for how duplicate questions are typically handled. Consider putting a bounty on the original question; would it be a waste if you gain an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Amazon** and **eBay** are not using In-App Purchases (IAP) to purchase their products.  For instance, I have an app that allows an IAP for users to access other features of the app.  The purchases are made in the app for something that is part of the app and the users are able to pay via **iTunes/AppStore** payment process.

**Amazon** and **eBay** allow you to make purchases thru their apps but they're not done for things like '*no advertising*' or '*add social media access*'.  They're for goods and services that are not being made thru the Apple-provided buying medium, **iTunes** or the **App Store**.  So these purchases are not IAP purchases.